Why my CircleCI config can not find a definition for executor named gcp-storage/default?
I want to run my Python script that produces bacup folder and then push it to GCP Storage.
Steps are run python,then push folers into GCP. I added the workspace so that folder could be persisted to workspace.
Build jobs passes when I delete the rest,but I need the upload part as well.
My config.yml
jobs:
  build:
    executor: python/default
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: mkdir -p workspace
      - run: echo "Hello, world!" > workspace/echo-output
      - python/install-packages:
          pkg-manager: pip
      - python/install-packages:
          pip-dependency-file: requirements.txt
          pkg-manager: pip
      - python/install-packages:
          args: pytest
          pkg-manager: pip
          pypi-cache: false
      - run:
          command: |
            pytest --version
          name: Test
      - run:
          name: Show all files
          command: find "$(pwd)"
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: workspace
          paths: 
            - echo-output

  use-gcp:
    executor: gcp-cli/default
    steps:
      - gcp-cli/setup:
          version: 330.0.0

  push-public-folder:
      executor: gcp-storage/default
      steps:
        - attach_workspace:
           at: workspace/echo-output

        - setup_directquery_cloud_credentials

        - gcp-storage/upload:
              source_path: echo-output
              destination_bucket: backup_folder
              cache_control: public, max-age=86400

workflows:
  main:
    jobs:
      - build
      - use-gcp
      - push-public-folder

fails.
What is wrong with my executor?
temp log file form VSCode shows
1. [#/jobs/build] only 1 subschema matches out of 2
|   1. [#/jobs/build] extraneous key [push-public-folder] is not permitted
|   |   Permitted keys:
|   |     - description
|   |     - parallelism
|   |     - macos
|   |     - resource_class
|   |     - docker
|   |     - steps
|   |     - working_directory
|   |     - circleci_ip_ranges
|   |     - machine
|   |     - environment
|   |     - executor
|   |     - shell
|   |     - parameters


[#/jobs/build] expected type: String, found: Mapping
|   Job may be a string reference to another job
How to fix this? Not too many examples that I can find.

